# Permission denied on some shared libraries

Tags: permissions, libraries, shared-library

First of all, I hope this is the right site to be posting this to.

I get these errors when logging in as another user (ignatius):

```
catch22bbs:~/Desktop # su ignatius
ls: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

And, also when running certain programs. Most of them don't work.

```
ignatius@catch22bbs:~> pico
pico: error while loading shared libraries: libmagic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

Here's the strange part:

```
catch22bbs:~ # l /usr/lib/libpcre.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Jun 29 06:04 /usr/lib/libpcre.so -> libpcre.so.1.2.7*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Jun 29 06:04 /usr/lib/libpcre.so.1 -> libpcre.so.1.2.7*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 488800 Jun 29 06:04 /usr/lib/libpcre.so.1.2.7*
```

And..

```
catch22bbs:~ # l /usr/lib/libmagic*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 Mar 14 05:53 /usr/lib/libmagic.so.1 -> libmagic.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 137032 Mar 14 05:55 /usr/lib/libmagic.so.1.0.0
```

I'm running openSuSE Tumbleweed. I've never had this problem in the past.
I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Run `ldconfig` and then check..

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help.

Comment: Do you have `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set?  If so, `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Still.. nothing..

Comment: Well, not literally nothing, you know what I mean..

Comment: Try `su - ignatius`.

Comment: catch22bbs:~/Desktop # su - ignatius
/usr/bin/manpath: error while loading shared libraries: libman-2.7.1.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
ls: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_COLLATE: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): Permission denied
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): Permission denied
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_MESSAGES: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): Permission denied

Comment: -bash: warning: setlocale: LC_NUMERIC: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): Permission denied
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_TIME: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): Permission denied
sed: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
sed: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied

Comment: You didn't do the `ls` running as `ignatius`: it's possible that running as **root** you modified the directory permissions.

Comment: What does `ls -ld / /usr /usr/lib` say? Seems like you messed up some of parent directory permissions.

Answer (score 5):

Barring something *really* obscure with your account, it's most likely that you modified some part of the directory permissions so that only *root* can access it.  There's been a couple of questions recently which amounted to having broken the system by doing

```
chmod 700 /
```

which can be repaired by doing

```
chmod 755 /
```

(both running as *root*, of course).  Besides the **`/`** level, your system directories may have incorrect permissions on `/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib` (both should be `0755`).

Comment: no problem (if it addressed the question, you might mark it accepted).

Comment: also check `/` rights

Comment: I think `umask 077` in `/etc/profile` can cause this issue on a system upgrade - `chmod 755 /` fixed it